# How to add class in li then ul under li once click any item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I fall an issue and have been trying to solve it for few hours but couldn't. I have a sidemenu bar which is as following format:

```
<ul class="collapse" id="menu">
    <li class="panel active">// class "active" should be added <a data-target="#dashboard-nav" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#">
            <i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></span>
        </a>

        <ul id="dashboard-nav" class="collapse in">// class "in" should be added
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i>Default Style</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> Alternative Style</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel"> <a data-target="#registrations-nav" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Registrations<span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></span>
        </a>

        <ul id="registrations-nav" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Create Registration</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-list"></i> List Registration</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-adn"></i> Manage Registration</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel"> <a data-target="#settings-nav" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#">
            <i class="icon-wrench"></i> Settings <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i> </span>
        </a>

        <ul id="settings-nav" class="collapse in">
            <li class="active"><a href="/ssw/index.php/admin/service/create"><i class="icon-leaf"></i> Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> Sites</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> Service Points</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Once I click any item of `<li class="panel">` a class "active" should be added in it as `<li class="panel active">` and also "in" class in following `'<ul>` as 
`<li class="panel">
    ...
    <ul id="dashboard-nav" class="collapse in">`
Please let me know if I couldn't explain clearly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xG7Qs/3/)

```
$('li.panel').click(function () {
    $('li.panel').removeClass('active');//remove active class from all li with class panel
    $('li.panel').children('ul').removeClass('in');//remove in class
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add class active to current li
    $(this).children('ul').addClass('in'); //add in class to the children ul
});
```

References

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: thanks to prompt reply. I have almost reached but I should click the item of `$('li.panel')` that would be `$('li.panel ul li')`. In this circumstance, how to solve. Please help me.

Comment: However, I have fixed the issue using parent() thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

I made a javascript solution for it as follows:-

```
        window.onload=start;
        function start(){
            var list = document.getElementById("menu").childNodes;
            for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                list[i].onclick=clicked;
            }
        }
        function clicked(){
            var input = this;
            input.className = "panel active"
            var child = input.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            child.className = "collaspe in"
        }
```